# What constraints am I missing for this to work on all iPhones in Compact?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I'm new to coding and trying to learn xCode/Swift. I'm confused on how I can get these 4 imageviews to show correctly on any iPhone in compact mode. I've set the constraints in compact mode but here is what they look like in iPhone 6 Plus, 6 and 5. Can someone help me with this? I'll also add a picture of what my current constraints look like. I'd like them to be center screen with a small gap of about 5 between each box (want them close to together but not touching).

**What they look like in simulator:**

[image]

**Current constraints:**

[image]

Comment: A simpler alternative would be to use `UIStackView`s which were designed for layouts like this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/

Comment: When I click that link it state page cannot be found.

Comment: Stack Overview mangled the link. It's the `UIStackView Class Reference`

Answer (score 0):

In your case better way is to set constraints not to top, leading and trailing, but to centerX and centerY.

And set width and height of views proportional to screen width and height.

Answer (score 0):

If you need fixed width of uiimageviews, you should align all views to centerX, set fixed width and height and set Y value, also if you need all views central you can set Y value to centerY. Don't forget to change '0' to current canvas value in horizantally\vertically alignment

[Contrains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgnSm.png)

[simulators preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3wsK.png)

Comment: I thought I responded here but I don't see my reply so typing it again. Thanks for the answer. Where do I change current canvas value to 0 and why do I need to do that?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Set the teal view's color to default(clear) color]

Hope this will help, ask me if you need more explaination.
Here the View.centerY = centerY and View.centerX = centerX is set for the subview(teal color view) of the main view.

Note: Set the teal view's color to default(clear) color

Result: 
[image: result of constraints]